# Are the raw bytes written by .NET System.IO.BinaryWriter readable by other platforms?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, f#, rust

## Background

I am manually writing a large data block into a binary file with `System.IO.BinaryWriter`. I have chosen this due to the improved performance compared to a wide variety of other means of serialization & deserialization (I am currently deserializing with `System.IO.BinaryReader`).

## Question

I may need to use the serialized formats in other programming languages like `Java` and/or `Rust`. Would they be able to understand the raw binary written by `System.IO.BinaryWriter` and read it in a similar manner to .NETs 'System.IO.BinaryReader'?

(I am assuming that the new plaforms (Java/Rust) will have implicit knowledge of the specific order in which the raw binary was written.)

## Side Info

I am aware that protocol buffers is meant to be a performant and language agnostic framework for serializing/deserializing in this scenario but:
(1) I am using F# and it struggles with the discriminated unions
(2) It wasn't really that much effort to write my own custom serializer as my types aren't too complex

Comment: If the basic types `int` `double` `char` etc are the same byte size and bit-format between the languages, everything should work as expected.

Comment: As far as I know, BinaryWriter and BinaryReader are the most portable way to do what you describe. Serializing with the formatters from System.Runtime.Serialization is is my experience only good if you put them in their own library/dll because they bother you if you move between namespaces.

Comment: @SimpleVar Can you elaborate on the term `bit-format`?

Comment: Like for example `double` has some "float" bits and exp bits and sign bit and those sections have certain logic, with specific lengths and locations. Not sure if those rules might vary between languages or architectures. The safest route would be to implement your own `ReadBin` and `WriteBin` for every type, and use equivalent implementations between the different languages. Otherwise consider using Json.

Comment: seems like a job for [FsPickler](https://nessos.github.io/FsPickler/) and probably a non-binary format (I am aware that it don't won't to be a cross-plattform framework - but it works anyway ;))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the types you write with the `BinaryWriter`.

- `byte`, `sbyte` and `byte[]`: no problem.
- `(U)IntXX`: matter of endianness. The .NET `BinaryWriter` dumps these types in little endian format.
- `float` and `double`: If both systems use the same IEEE 754 standard, and both systems use the same endianness, then it is no problem.
- `decimal`: This is a .NET-specific type, similar to `Currency` but uses different format. Use carefully.
- `char` and `char[]`: Uses the current `Encoding` of the `BinaryWriter`. Use the same encoding on both sides and everything is alright.
- `string`: The length of the string is encoded in the so-called *7 bit-encoded int* format (1 byte for up to 127 chars, etc), *and* uses the current encoding. To make things compatible maybe you should dump character arrays with manually dumped length information.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

```
bool     --> 0 | 1
sbyte    --> x
byte[]   --> xxxxxx
char[]   --> encoding.getbytes(char[])
byte     --> x
char     --> 
decimal  --> decimal.GetBytes(), 16 bytes, should see the System.Decimal class code
double   --> 8 bytes, should see the System.Double class code
short    --> 2 bytes, <lsb><msb>
int      --> 4 byets, <lsb>xx<msb>
long     --> 8 bytes, <lsb>xxxxxx<msb>
float    --> 4 bytes, should see the System.Single class code
string   --> 7 bit encoded length (variable size) + encoding.GetBytes(), see 7 bit encoding method below
ushort   --> same as short
uint     --> same as int
ulong    --> same as long
```

For numeric types, data is written in [Little Endian Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking)

```
protected void Write7BitEncodedInt(int value)
{
    uint num = (uint) value;
    while (num >= 0x80)
    {
        this.Write((byte) (num | 0x80));
        num = num >> 7;
    }
    this.Write((byte) num);
}
```